# Avoid Empty data from Model in a Foreach Statement

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have this Loop wich compares data from 1 of my models:

```
        foreach (var record in model_pdv)
        {
            foreach (var dish in record.Data)
            {
                int index = dish.Fecha.Day;
                record.Days[index] = dish.Cantidad;
                record.TotalQuantity += dish.Cantidad;
            }
            record.TotalPrice = (record.TotalQuantity * record.Precio);
        }
```

However my first field in my record.Data is an empty field so my foreach gives me a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

How can i avoid empty data in my "Data" Field, its a list and the first list is empty

I can show the LinQ code if its helps

EDIT****************************

SOLVED
Solved the problem adding a If Statement in my foreach loop

```
foreach (var record in model_pdv)
        {
  if (!record.Data.Any()){
            foreach (var dish in record.Data)
            {
                int index = dish.Fecha.Day;
                record.Days[index] = dish.Cantidad;
                record.TotalQuantity += dish.Cantidad;
            }
            record.TotalPrice = (record.TotalQuantity * record.Precio);
 }            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: More info about data types would be helpful..
Try this one:

How about this?

```
    foreach (var record in model_pdv.Where(r => r.Data != null))
    {
        foreach (var dish in record.Data)
        {
            int index = dish.Fecha.Day;
            record.Days[index] = dish.Cantidad;
            record.TotalQuantity += dish.Cantidad;
        }
        record.TotalPrice = (record.TotalQuantity * record.Precio);
    }
```

Comment: Still the same problem, its because Data has a empty value wich i want to avoid

Comment: I still do not understand it well. The issue is, that foreach is no problems with empty data. Empty data is an array with no items. List with no items in it. But not null.  null is not empty, null is non-existent...  Now index can be out of range, but not foreach...